# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [28332, 24]

Tags: python, nlp, multilabel-classification

I am currently working with multilabel text classification in the Arabic language using binary relevance and label power set, after I make all preprocessing that I need when I need to combine chi and mutual feature selection based on their weights, I am facing this problem
`Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [28332, 24]`
where my dataset has one column have the text and 24 columns as a target as shown in the image :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ4Yk.png)
I am writing this code

```
`class Classifier:
    def __init__(self):
        self.merged_df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\project\Ymal.csv", encoding='utf-8')
        self.train_df, self.test_df = train_test_split(self.merged_df,test_size=0.2,random_state=42) 
        self.vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
        self.ModelsPerformance = {}
    def train(self):
        self.train_text = self.train_df['text']
        self.test_text = self.test_df['text']
        self.train_labels = self.train_df.drop(columns=['text'])
        self.test_labels = self.test_df.drop(columns=['text'])
        self.mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
        self.train_labels = self.mlb.fit_transform(self.train_labels)
        self.test_labels = self.mlb.transform(self.test_labels)
        self.train_text_bow = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(self.train_text)
        self.test_text_bow = self.vectorizer.transform(self.test_text)
        self.chi2_selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k='all',)
        self.mi_selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif, k='all',)
        self.chi2_features = self.chi2_selector.fit_transform(self.train_text_bow,self.train_labels)     
        self.mi_features = self.mi_selector.fit_transform(self.train_text_bow,self.train_labels)
        self.weights_chi2 = self.chi2_selector.scores_ 
        self.weights_mi = self.mi_selector.scores_
        self.weights = (self.weights_chi2 + self.weights_mi ) / 2
        self.top_features = np.argsort(self.weights)[-4000:]  #[::-1]
        self.train_combined_features = self.train_text_bow[:,self.top_features]
        self.test_text_bow = self.vectorizer.transform(self.test_text)
        self.test_combined_features = self.test_text_bow[:, self.top_features]
    def metricsReport(self,modelName, test_labels, predictions):
        hamLoss = hamming_loss(test_labels, predictions)
        print("------" + modelName + " Model Metrics-----")
        accuracy = accuracy_score(test_labels, predictions)
        macroPrecision = precision_score(test_labels, predictions, average='macro')
        macroRecall = recall_score(test_labels, predictions, average='macro')
        macroF1 = f1_score(test_labels, predictions, average='macro')
        microPrecision = precision_score(test_labels, predictions, average='micro')
        microRecall = recall_score(test_labels, predictions, average='micro')
        microF1 = f1_score(test_labels, predictions, average='micro')
        weightedF1 = f1_score(test_labels, predictions, average='weighted')
            # print metrics
        print("Hamming Loss: {:.4f}".format(hamLoss))
        print('Accuracy: {0:.4f}'.format(accuracy))
        print('Macro Precision: {0:.4f}'.format(macroPrecision))
        print('Macro Recall: {0:.4f}'.format(macroRecall))
        print('Macro F1-measure: {0:.4f}'.format(macroF1))
        print('Micro Precision: {0:.4f}'.format(microPrecision))
        print('Micro Recall: {0:.4f}'.format(microRecall))
        print('Micro F1-measure: {0:.4f}\n'.format(microF1)) 
        print('Weighted F1-measure: {0:.4f}\n'.format(weightedF1))         
    def fitAlgorithms(self):
        algorithms = [{'name': 'LinearSVC', 'model': LinearSVC(max_iter=12000, dual=False),
             'params': {'C': [0.1, 1, 10]}},
            {'name': 'KNN', 'model': KNeighborsClassifier(),
             'params': {'n_neighbors': [5, 10, 15]}},
            {'name': 'RandomForest', 'model': RandomForestClassifier(),
             'params': {'n_estimators': [100, 300, 500]}},
            {'name': 'LogisticRegression', 'model': LogisticRegression(),
             'params': {'C': [0.1, 1, 10]}},
            {'name': 'DecisionTree', 'model': DecisionTreeClassifier(),
             'params': {'max_depth': [5, 10, 15]}},
            {'name': 'MultinomialNB', 'model': MultinomialNB(),
             'params': {'alpha': [0.1, 1, 10]}}
        ]
        for algorithm in algorithms:
            model = algorithm['model']
            name = algorithm['name']
            params = algorithm['params']
        # Fit the binary relevance and label powerset classifiers before the grid search
            binary_relevance_classifier = BinaryRelevance(model)
            binary_relevance_classifier.fit(self.train_combined_features, self.train_labels)
            labelPowerSet_classifier = LabelPowerset(model)
            labelPowerSet_classifier.fit(self.train_combined_features, self.train_labels)
            print(f"Performing GridSearchCV for {name}...")
            clf = GridSearchCV(model, params, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
            clf.fit(self.train_combined_features, self.train_labels)
            best_params = clf.best_params_
            print(f"Best parameters for {name}: {best_params}")
            model.set_params(**best_params)
            binary_relevance_preds = binary_relevance_classifier.predict(self.test_combined_features)
            self.metricsReport(f"Binary Relevance with {name}", self.test_labels, binary_relevance_preds)
            labelPowerSet_preds = labelPowerSet_classifier.predict(self.test_combined_features)
            self.metricsReport(f"Label Powerset with {name}", self.test_labels, labelPowerSet_preds)
            self.ModelsPerformance[name] = clf.best_score_
        return self.ModelsPerformance
# Create an instance of the Classifier
classifier = Classifier()
# Invoke the training method
classifier.train()
# Invoke the fitAlgorithms() method
classifier.fitAlgorithms()
```

but this basic problem is this error I referee it above
please any one can help me and if any one can optimize this ?
I believe that error is clear but I cant avoid this , also i tried the do this to sure the shape but it fine
`print("train_text_bow shape:", train_text_bow.shape) print("train_labels shape:", train_labels.shape) train_text_bow shape: (28332, 121714) train_labels shape: (28332, 24)t`

I need just to avoid this error